# Chrome scrollbar is not visible, no yellow marker for ctrl + F search matches

Tags: google-chrome, lxde, openbox

In Chrome 41 running in openbox window manager, the scrollbar indicator for the page location is not visible. This occurs in all tabs, including incognito tabs, except for `chrome://settings`.

The space at the side of the screen is reserved, but nothing appears (see image below). For example, when using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to search words, yellow bars would normally appear to indicate areas on the current page that the search term is found.[2](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95635?hl=en-GB) This no longer appears.

I have attempted disabling extensions and restarting the browser. I have only seen one other [mention of this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topicsearchin/chrome/scrollbar%7Csort:relevance/chrome/ADmNTo4t4bk), but I do not wish to install a third part extension for such a basic browser functionality.

Any ideas?

The small dark gray area at the right of this image is just an lxpanel and unrelated to this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved by going to `chrome://flags/` and clicking the button labelled `Reset all to defaults`.

I am currently testing flag settings to reproduce the problem.

**Update:** The specific solution is to enable pinch virtual viewport by setting `chrome://flags/#enable-pinch-virtual-viewport` to `Default` or `Enable`.